# how to create a loop response in json?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, json

I am fetching data from 3 tables: `table.service_master_new`, `table.department_master` and `table.document_master`.

table structure:

[image: Structure of Service Master]

[image: Structure of Department master]

[image: Structure of Document Master]

Data in the table:

[image: Data of service table]

[image: data of department table]

[image: data of document table]

and my php code for fetching data is:

```php
<?php
include 'mysql.php';
$matrix = array();
$getServices = mysqli_query($db,"SELECT * FROM service_master_new");
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($getServices,MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
    $xmatrix = array();
    $dept_code = $row['dept_code'];
            $getDeptName = mysqli_query($db,"SELECT * FROM department_master WHERE Dept_Code='$dept_code'");
            while($row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($getDeptName,MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
                $xxmatrix = array();
                $dept_name = $row1['Dept_Name'];
                $xmatrix['dept_name'] = $dept_name;
                array_push($xmatrix, $dept_name);

                $service_name = $row['service_name'];
                $xmatrix['service_name'] = $service_name;
                array_push($xmatrix, $service_name);
                $contact_point = $row['contact_point'];
                $xmatrix['contact_point'] = $contact_point;
                array_push($xmatrix, $contact_point);
                $timeline = $row['timeline'];
                $xmatrix['timeline'] = $timeline;
                array_push($xmatrix, $timeline);

                $doc_codes = $row['doc_codes'];
                $xdocs = array();
                $codes = explode(",",$doc_codes);
                $countCodes = count($codes);
                for($i=0;$i<$countCodes;$i++){
                    $getDocs = mysqli_query($db,"SELECT * FROM document_master WHERE Doc_Code='$codes[$i]'");
                    while($row4 = mysqli_fetch_array($getDocs,MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
                        $doc_name = $row4['Doc_Name'];
                        array_push($xdocs, $doc_name);
                    }
                    $xmatrix['docs'] = $xdocs;
                }
        }


    array_push($matrix, $xmatrix);
}
echo json_encode($matrix);
?>
```

and this is the response I am getting:

```js
[
{
0: "Fire",
1: "No Objection Certificate",
2: "O/O Chief Fire Officer",
3: "15",
dept_name: "Fire",
service_name: "No Objection Certificate",
contact_point: "O/O Chief Fire Officer",
timeline: "15",
docs: [
"Record of Rights Form 'F'",
"Sketch Map",
"Approved Building Plan",
"Statutory License to carry business",
"Building Stability Certificate",
"Quantity & Completion certificate of Electrical wiring from recognized Authority"
]
},
{
0: "Electricity",
1: "New Electricity Connection (LT)",
2: "O/O Assistant Engineer, IPP, HQ",
3: "30",
dept_name: "Electricity",
service_name: "New Electricity Connection (LT)",
contact_point: "O/O Assistant Engineer, IPP, HQ",
timeline: "30",
docs: [
"Record of Rights Form 'F'",
"Sketch Map",
"Identity Proof"
]
},
{
0: "Electricity",
1: "New Electricity Connection (HT)",
2: "O/O Assistant Engineer, IPP, HQ",
3: "45",
dept_name: "Electricity",
service_name: "New Electricity Connection (HT)",
contact_point: "O/O Assistant Engineer, IPP, HQ",
timeline: "45",
docs: [
"Record of Rights Form 'F'",
"Sketch Map",
"Identity Proof"
]
},
{
0: "Electricity",
1: "New Electricity Connection (Extra HT)",
2: "O/O Assistant Engineer, IPP, HQ",
3: "180",
dept_name: "Electricity",
service_name: "New Electricity Connection (Extra HT)",
contact_point: "O/O Assistant Engineer, IPP, HQ",
timeline: "180",
docs: [
"Record of Rights Form 'F'",
"Sketch Map",
"Identity Proof"
]
},
{
0: "APWD",
1: "Planning Permissin ",
2: "PBMC / Concerned Panchayat",
3: "15",
dept_name: "APWD",
service_name: "Planning Permissin ",
contact_point: "PBMC / Concerned Panchayat",
timeline: "15",
docs: [
"Record of Rights Form 'F'",
"Sketch Map",
"Building Plan / Site Plan",
"Statement of proposed Development",
"Document of Ownership & title of Property",
"Receipt of Payment of Application Fee"
]
},
{
0: "PBMC",
1: "Planning Permissin ",
2: "PBMC",
3: "160",
dept_name: "PBMC",
service_name: "Planning Permissin ",
contact_point: "PBMC",
timeline: "160",
docs: [
"Building Plan / Site Plan",
"Document of Ownership & title of Property",
"Form of Notice of Intention to errect a Building or to execute any work as prescribed in Appendix 'A'",
"Form of notice of Completion Appendix 'E'",
"Form of Occupancy Certificate Appendix 'F, G & H'",
"Performa of details of Construction of Building around Port Blair Airport, Appendix I, IIA, IIB, IIC, IID, IIE & C"
]
},
{
0: "Labour",
1: "Licence Under the Factories ACT, 1948",
2: "O/O Labour Commissioner",
3: "60",
dept_name: "Labour",
service_name: "Licence Under the Factories ACT, 1948",
contact_point: "O/O Labour Commissioner",
timeline: "60",
docs: [
"Building Plan / Site Plan",
"Receipt of Payment of Application Fee",
"Site Map in the Scale (1cm : 20Mtrs)",
"Flow chart of the Manufacturing Process"
]
},
{
0: "Labour",
1: "Registration Under Contract Labour (R ",
2: "O/O Labour Commissioner",
3: "15",
dept_name: "Labour",
service_name: "Registration Under Contract Labour (R ",
contact_point: "O/O Labour Commissioner",
timeline: "15",
docs: [
"Receipt of Payment of Application Fee",
"Affidavit in Prescribed Format"
]
},
{
0: "Labour",
1: "Registration Under A ",
2: "O/O Labour Commissioner",
3: "30",
dept_name: "Labour",
service_name: "Registration Under A ",
contact_point: "O/O Labour Commissioner",
timeline: "30",
docs: [
"Form D and E as per Annexures"
]
},
{
0: "DC Office",
1: "Land Conversion",
2: "O/O Deputy Commissioner",
3: "28",
dept_name: "DC Office",
service_name: "Land Conversion",
contact_point: "O/O Deputy Commissioner",
timeline: "28",
docs: [
"Record of Rights Form 'F'",
"Sketch Map",
"Document of Ownership & title of Property",
"Project Report",
"Affidavit in Prescribed Format",
"Site Map in the Scale (1cm : 20Mtrs)",
"Photograph of the proposed site with the Signature"
]
},
{
0: "PCC",
1: "Common Consent to Establish, Operate",
2: "O/O A ",
3: "90",
dept_name: "PCC",
service_name: "Common Consent to Establish, Operate",
contact_point: "O/O A ",
timeline: "90",
docs: [
"Record of Rights Form 'F'",
"Sketch Map",
"Building Plan / Site Plan",
"Document of Ownership & title of Property",
"Notarized Affidavit in twenty rupees stamp paper or valuation certificate from Chartered Accountant giving details of Capital Investment including Land, Building and Plant & Machinery without depreciation",
"Registration Certificate of DIC",
"Project Report",
"CRZ-Clearance/Environmental Clearance / Noc from Forest Department of from Revenue Authority showing the distance of the Building / Unit from High Tide Level (HTL)",
"Copy of Permission granted for Ground water withdrawal from Competent Authority"
]
}
]
```

But I want the data to be arranged by their departments, like:

electricity dept should not come twice; it should be in another array inside electricity dept.

Comment: You may try "foreach in foreach" (nested foreach).

Comment: any suggestion or approach in doing so...

Comment: How is that *not* an approach for doing so?

Comment: can u explain briefly, or can u suggest me where to modify in my php code

Answer (score 0):

I'm just adding some example code, please modify it for yourself.

Lets say we have 3 different tables and we should fetch data from these tables and make it json output. Here an example code:

```
foreach ($table_one as $to) {

    foreach($table_two as $tt) {

        foreach($table_three as $ttr) {

         $data[]        =   array
         (
         'value1' => $ttr['value1'], 
         'value2' => $tt['value2'], 
         'value3' => $to['value3']
         );
         }
    }
}

$json   =   json_encode($data);
```

Remember, this is just an example. Don't forget to modify it for yourself!

Comment: iam jst a beginner in this, can u do it for me please.

Comment: If I make it you'll never learn. Just try, I'm sure that you can handle.

Comment: ok lemme try... thnx for the confidence... so you gave me a php snippet rite?

Comment: Yes, I gave you an example snippet. You should modify it but don't change main structure, you should use foreach in foreach.

Comment: <?php
include 'mysql.php';
$matrix = array();
$getServices = mysqli_query($db,"SELECT * FROM service_master_new");
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($getServices,MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
 $xmatrix = array();
 $dept_code = $row['dept_code'];
   $getDeptName = mysqli_query($db,"SELECT * FROM department_master WHERE Dept_Code='$dept_code'");
   while($row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($getDeptName,MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
    $xxmatrix = array();
    $dept_name = $row1['Dept_Name'];
    $xmatrix['dept_name'] = $dept_name;
    array_push($xmatrix, $dept_name);
    foreach ($dept_name as $dp) {

Comment: iam totally confused rite now? should i remove my whole code and edit ur snippet as my requirement or should i integrate ur snippet in my code?

Comment: sorry i cant... if u can the please share it with me. i would be very grateful.